# SuperSearch - Filtering results with edit date

Tags: supersearch, edit-date

Is there a way to filter supersearch results such that only entries edited after a certain date will be searched for? Our database is going to be massive and we don't want to load the db will excessive MySQL calls.

I've tried using

```
{exp:super_search:results 
channel="record" 
status="open|closed" 
edit_date-from=20130501040000}
     {entry_id}
{/exp:super_search:results}
```